# How to have records count on the last row of select query?

Tags: sql, select

I need to have records count of a select query at the last line. 
My client needs report with records count at bottom of his report.

Something like this:

```
Select * from My_table where id>5
union all 
select ('Record Count: ' + count(*)) from My_table where id>5
```

Comment: If it's SQL Server you can use `@@RowCount` after the query.

Comment: why does it have to be the same query? Can't you just write an application where you call these queries separately and include them in the report?

Comment: Most reporting tools provide a very easy mechanism to add a footer with the count - unless you're printing straight from SQL this logic belongs in the UI/Report layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: I use SSIS Package to generate report and it doesn't have any option to add footer.